# What are the steps to import the UNIX db2 server dump file in the windows db2 server?

Tags: db2

Explanation:- I have the client database DB2 which is on Unix server and i need the dump of the data from there. And now in our local environment we have DB2 database on the windows server. Now I want to know how can import the UNIX db2 dump into windows db2 server.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to recreate a DB2 database from UNIX into Windows is via db2look + db2move

On source server

```
db2look -d mydb -e
db2move mydb export
```

On target server

```
db2 -tvf myDDL.sql
db2move mydb import
```

The backup files cannot be used because there is an Endian incompatibility between these platforms: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0005960.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, will try and check whether this option works.